# Health insurance questioning my finances again

Tags: germany, health-insurance, health

I moved to Munich in November and after months of trying I eventually managed to get a state policy with Mobil Oil. I saw a doctor and was referred to hospital for an operation. Before I arrived home 3 days later, they sent a letter to me with pages of questions, which my German friend says are about money and costs.

I am unemployed and under pension age, surviving on a small private pension, the details of which they already known, and some savings in England. I pay for my policy from a German bank account. Can they demand more money after agreeing to my policy cost already? I can’t believe that I am obliged to give them details of my savings in England. Surely only government tax authorities can do this?

Comment: "About money and costs" can mean a lot of things. What are the questions exactly?

Comment: What do you call 'state policy'?

Comment: Please provide more relevant details. Do you have private or public health insurance in Germany? What is your status for that insurance? If you are "voluntarily insured" (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freiwillige_Krankenversicherung), then of course you need to provide details on all your savings (including ones in England), so that the insurance company can calculate your payment correctly (which is then based on your total income, including but not limiting to all interest you get from all your deposits, not only in England). This probably has nothing to do with your hospital stay.

Answer (score 4):

It's much different than you think. The German public health insurance will simply ask you to provide your German and your UK tax bill and if you refuse to give it to them, they assume you are earning as much as the **Beitragsbemessungsgrenze** (about 50.000 €) each year. And calculate your fee accordingly.

They will ask you for these documents each year.

Comment: Thanks everyone. You were right. This is a routine questionnaire just to confirm that my details are unchanged. Apologies for wasting anyone’s time.